# Crash on startup

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

The StackExchange app crashes for me on every start when I click a link in the browser. It seems (based on the StackTrace) that the url parser causes a null pointer exception. I'm using 0.1.90.

Comment: Does this happen on any URL or specific URLs only?

Comment: That happens on every question. If I start the app directly or via notifications everything works fine for me.

Comment: I have the same issue, it is a bit more detailled there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217530/opening-stackexchange-app-from-chrome-via-a-link-crashes?noredirect=1#comment704971_217530

Comment: It seems to been fixed. It works now with 1.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed as of version 1.0.0, thanks!