# Opening Android SE app from Chrome via a link crashes

Tags: bug, android-app

When I searched on Google on Nexus 7: `javascript+date+formatting`, and clicked the first link, I was redirected to the Stack Exchange app (which I want), but the app crashed.

I'm not sure if this happened since the new release, but it is really annoying. Here are the details of the report:

> Sourcefile: ComponentName.java, line 77, exception java.lang.NullPointerException.

I have also sent the crash report, so you can have more information about this.

Comment: The other question could be about FF, Iceweasel, Internet explorer etc. Until that's know we can't mark this as a dupe of it.

Comment: @James No look at the tags. It's both about the official Android App.

Comment: Yes but the issue may not be the app, it might be the browser (or os/device/etc) being used to open it. This question: "*opening stackexchange app from chrome via a link crashes*" - and the other question: "*The StackExchange app crashes for me on every start when I click a link in the browser*". However unlikely, it might be two different issues. Even if not, until the two questions are deemed as the same scenario (app version, browser, OS, Device, etc) I don't think they're a dupe.

Comment: @edi9999 What version are you using? rekire said the issue went away with version 1.0.0.

Comment: I'm using version 0.1.90 of stackecchange app

Comment: @edi9999 the linked question in rene's comment states they used that version too, and using 1.0.0 resolved it for them.

Comment: That works for me too on 1.0.0